# Error when using proj4 in visual C++ (cannot compile project using proj4 lib)

Tags: proj, visual-c++

I am using Proj4 version 4.8.0, after compiled by vc i had  proj.dll and proj.lib
But when i used proj.lib in my project vc++, i cannot compile that project.
Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "proj_api.h";
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = 138494.92605;
    double y = 467792.640021;

    char *srid28992 = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.04,49.91,465.84,-1.9848,1.7439,-9.0587,4.0772 +units=m +no_defs";
    char *srid4326 = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";

    projPJ source = pj_init_plus(srid28992);
    projPJ target = pj_init_plus(srid4326);

    if(source==NULL || target==NULL)
        return false;

    //  x *= DEG_TO_RAD;
    //  y *= DEG_TO_RAD;

    int success = pj_transform(source, target, 1, 1, &x, &y, NULL );

    x *= RAD_TO_DEG;
    y *= RAD_TO_DEG;

    cout << success << endl << x << endl << y << endl;
}
```

Here is message of visual studio :

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Proj4ApiExam, Configuration: Debug
>   Win32 ------ 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _pj_transform referenced in function _main 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _pj_init_plus referenced in
>   function _main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify **Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies** adding **proj.lib**
and modify **Project > Properties > Linker > General >  Additional Library Directories** with the path to **proj.lib**